# PHP Storing password the good way

Tags: php, passwords

since the new password_ library for PHP is kinda vague information vise. I was thinking maybe you have more experience then I.

I am working on storing password the good way.

```
$options = ['cost' => 11,'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)];
$u = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Is this the way to do it? Can it be improved somehow?

Comment: use one way encryption like sha1() or md5()

Comment: just don't put the $_POST directly. the rest looks good imo

Comment: @Sundar - recommending insecure hashes (without even mentioning salting) when OP is asking about the recommended solution to password handling in PHP isn't a very wise suggestion

Comment: okay i have to study php 5.5 thanks for the update

Comment: Even before php 5.5 md5 or sha1 should be salted to make it a little more secure ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is nearly the way to do it. In most cases it is best to omit the salt parameter. Without this parameter, the function will generate a cryptographically safe salt, from the random source of the operating system.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 11));

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

A bit more in detail: your method to generate a salt will require more random bytes than necessary, because BCrypt expects an encoded salt, not a binary salt as you create. As far as i know the function password_hash will encode it properly, but it would use only the necessary bytes.

Note: In this case you can use $_POST['password'] directly as you did (escaping is not necessary), because the hash function works with all kind of input and will generate a "safe" string, which is not prone to SQL-injection.